# Why is some virtual network interface assigned private IP address, while some is assigned loopback IP address?

Tags: ip-address, private-network, loopback

Are `docker0`, `lo` and  `virbr0` are virtual network interfaces?

Why are `docker0` and `virbr0` assigned private not loopback IP address?

If private IP address can work like a loopback address, can `lo` be assigned a prviate instead of loopback IP address?

Loopback addresses are `127.*.*.*`. Do they always form a network instead of being split into several smaller networks, as in the example?

`192.168.*.*` is a range of private IP addresses. Are they often split into several smaller networks, as in the example (`wlx8` and `virbr0`)?

Thanks.

```
$ ifconfig
docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:a6:79:a6:bc  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1552397  bytes 88437726 (88.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1552397  bytes 88437726 (88.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:b1:aa:1f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 123  bytes 12102 (12.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 39  bytes 4300 (4.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlx8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.97  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::a0df:c436:afb1:8b45  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether   txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 991338  bytes 536052615 (536.0 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 618233  bytes 101520924 (101.5 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: The private addresses do not work the same as loopback adresses. A packet sent to a private address is not looped back. A rfc1918 ("private") address is simply an adress from a blocks reserved for use "inside an organization", but with the ipv4 address shortage, more and more clients are only assigned such addresses by ISPs, which are then using some form of NAT to let them use the Internet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What constitutes a “network” (a set of endpoints which are reachable without the help of routers) is determined by the netmask here. Thus `docker0` is on the 172.17.x.x network (and can talk to any 172.17.x.x endpoint in the same layer 2 network), `lo` is on the 127.x.x.x network, `virbr0` is on the 192.168.122.x network (and can talk to any 192.168.122.x endpoint in the same layer 2 network), and `wlx8` is on the 192.168.1.x network (I’ll let you fill in), and they’re all separate. The loopback network is special in that by default, all 127.x.x.x addresses correspond to the local host.

> Are `docker0`, `lo` and `virbr0` are virtual network interfaces?

Yes, they don’t correspond to physical network interfaces.

> Why are `docker0` and `virbr0` assigned private not loopback IP address?

Because they are not loopback interfaces. Such interfaces are generally used to communicate with containers or VMs, which are separate (from a networking perspective, which is what concerns us here) from the local host.

> If private IP address can work like a loopback address, can `lo` be assigned a prviate instead of loopback IP address?

No, private IP addresses don’t work like a loopback address. (They can be made to work in any way you want, but that’s for networking experts and people who design systems such as Istio with Envoy, which uses an interesting loopback trick for multi-cluster setups.)

> Loopback addresses are `127.*.*.*`. Do they always form a network instead of being split into several smaller networks, as in the example?

See my first point.

> `192.168.*.*` is a range of private IP addresses. Are they often split into several smaller networks, as in the example (`wlx8` and `virbr0`)?

Yes; again, see my first point.

Comment: Thanks. (1) Loopback addresses are 127.*.*.*. Are they normally assigned to the same virtual network interface, or to different virtual network interface? For example, if a process sends a request to 127.0.0.2:2000, will a process listening at 127.0.0.1:2000 receive it? (2) I am still not sure: do 127.*.*.* addresses always form a network instead of being split into several smaller networks, as in the example?

Comment: Loopback addresses don’t need to be assigned; try pinging different loopback addresses, you’ll see answers (from the local host) even though they’re not assigned. However they’re distinguished when binding, so a process listening on 127.0.0.1:2000 won’t receive traffic directed to 127.0.0.2:2000 (try it with `nc`). Perhaps my first point wasn’t clear: 127.x.x.x forms a single network.

Comment: ifconfig doesn't show any interface with 127.0.0.2. Is such a virtual network interface exist? If I ping it, should the virtual network respond?

Comment: Re-read what I wrote, and try it.

Comment: Maybe I miss something. `ping 127.0.0.2` can receives response. But ifconfig doesn't show any interface with 127.0.0.2. Is such a virtual network interface exist? How shall I understand it? Is `ping` supposed to test if a network interface for an IP address exists and is working?

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is to demonstrate that loopback addresses don’t need to be assigned to interfaces. `ping` tests whether packets can be sent to and received back from a given IP address, no more, no less; it doesn’t concern itself with network interfaces.

Comment: Are loopback addresses the only IP addresses which don't need to be assigned to a network interface or something else? Why is 127.0.0.1 still assigned to a virtual network interface `lo`, if it doesn't need to be to work?

Comment: You’ve asked a separate question for your first point, so I won’t answer it here. `lo` gets an IP address assigned to it so that packets sent from it have a source IP address.

Comment: Thanks. "Such devices are generally used to communicate with containers or VMs, which are separate (from a networking perspective, which is what concerns us here) from the local host." (1) By "the local host", do you mean a loop back IP address? (2) docker0 and virbr0 are in their own private networks, and is the host machine in their private networks. How can they communicate with the host machine?

Comment: By local host, I mean the system running everything. `docker0` and `virb0` are in their own private networks, but the interfaces are on the local host; so the host can communicate with every container or VM on the corresponding private networks. The isolation applies between containers or VMs on different private networks (so containers can talk to each other, but not to VMs, and vice versa), and between containers/VMs and the “external” network (so containers/VMs can’t talk to the Internet). You can add routers to connect the networks, as is often done to provide access to the Internet.

Comment: How "the host can communicate with every container or VM"? The host isn't in the convainer or VM private networks.

Comment: Where do you think the interfaces you see in `ifconfig`’s output are?

Comment: I am not sure what you asked. Could you answer my question directly?

Comment: I could, but I don’t want to, I’d like you to think about this a bit more. Why do you think the host isn’t in the container or private networks?

Comment: Because I don't know, I don't claim it is. If it is, what is its IP address (and network interface name) in the container/VM's private networks?

Comment: You *wrote* “The host isn’t in the container or VM private networks”. You can see its IP addresses and network interfaces in the container and VM networks in `ifconfig`’s output.

Comment: Thanks. My apology. My VM guest OS is Windows. I installed docker, but haven't got to know how to use it.

Comment: I try to understand what you meant by "lo gets an IP address assigned to it so that packets sent from it have a source IP address." Is the network interface `lo` created first, and then an IP address (here 127.0.0.1) is assigned to it? Without an IP address, `lo` is not possible to have packets send to or receive from it?

Comment: Try it: `sudo ip addr delete 127.0.0.1 dev lo`, then `ping 127.0.0.1`.

Comment: it doesn't respond to ping. Isn't a loop back address supposed to work without being assigned to a network interface? Could you address my previous questions explicitly?

Comment: The interface can exist without having an IP address, but it can only be used for IP traffic if it has an IP address (directly or indirectly).

Comment: Thanks. In your earlier comment "The isolation applies ... between containers/VMs and the external network (so containers/VMs can’t talk to the Internet). You can add routers to connect the networks, as is often done to provide access to the Internet." By default, VMs created by virt-manager and KVM/QEMU can connect to the Internet. So I was wondering what you mean by isolation between VMs and the Internet, and need to add router to connect them?

Comment: The host acts as a router if configured to do so, and in QEMU’s case, QEMU acts as a router. See the `-nic` options in QEMU’s documentation.

Comment: The routing table of the host OS seems to imply the host OS is a router. Does that mean the same as "QEMU acts as a router"?

Comment: Have you read the QEMU networking documentation?

Comment: I have tried, but I don't quite understand https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/Networking#The_new_-nic_option. I am still not sure what you mean by isolation between VMs and the Internet, and need to add router to connect them.

Comment: If you set up network connectivity for VMs using different private networks, and only that, the various networks will be isolated from each other. To allow communication between networks, you need a router. In QEMU’s case, QEMU acts as a router by default for its VM (but it’s not the host OS, and it doesn’t configure the host OS to be a router).

Answer (score 1):

> Are `docker0`, `lo` and  `virbr0` are virtual network interfaces?

Yes.

They are not all the same type.  All it means is they are not provided by a hardware device.  Virtual devices are listed in `/sys/devices/virtual/`.  Look in the `net/` subdirectory.

> If private IP address can work like a loopback address,

I don't know what you mean

> can `lo` be assigned a prviate instead of loopback IP address?

Yes.  Worked fine for me, try it yourself.  `ip addr add <ADDR> dev lo`.

> Loopback addresses are `127.*.*.*`. Do they always form a network instead of being split into several smaller networks, as in the example?

I don't really know.  But I am suspicious of any software that relies on splitting `127.*.*.*`.  In IPv6, you only get one loopback address `::1`.  Because the authors did not find any good reasons for having a whole loopback network (let alone 2^24 such addresses).  So, it is clear it was not used very much.

> `192.168.*.*` is a range of private IP addresses. Are they often split into several smaller networks, as in the example (`wlx8` and  `virbr0`)?

Splitting `192.168.*.*` into subnets is absolutely the most common way of using it.  Your home router almost certainly uses `192.168.0.*` or `192.168.1.*` by default.  This helps when you want to configure multiple subnets - e.g. a second network for guest Wi-Fi access, which is firewalled from your main network.

> Why are `docker0` and `virbr0` assigned private not loopback IP address?

Why would they not be?

More specifically, the IPv4 standard could reasonably be interpreted as [requiring all the loopback addresses to behave as loopbacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-3).  This means that it is not legal to use them e.g. to communicate between a docker container and a docker host.  Because they would no longer work as loopback addresses.

Maybe the standard requirement means something else.  I.e. maybe it could be legal to use them to construct more complex virtual networks, if you never let them touch a physical network.  The standard does not clarify this point.  Where the loopback network is supported, it has generally been interpreted in the same way as Linux has.  So people are used to that implementation, and would be confused to see something different.